# how to run scheduler just after inserting data into database in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

I am new to spring boot and I have a requirement in which I have to run scheduler only if new data is inserted into table. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has an interceptor mecanism that allows you to get notified, at specific times, when database events occurs.

Such events are creation/deletion/flush of the session. As you get access to the objects being subject to the given event, you have a mean to fire a process when a given object of a given class (which you can easily map to a table in your schema) is modified.

The javadoc can be found here :
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html

You can use the interceptor mecanism along with Java's **ScheduledExecutorService** to schedule a task when hibernate intercepts the save operation. You can create your business logic under that interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling is not enabled by default. Before adding any scheduled jobs we need to enable scheduling explicitly by adding the @enableScheduling annotation.

Now with the help of the ScheduledTaskRegistrar#addTriggerTask method, we can add a Runnable task and a Trigger implementation to recalculate the next execution time after the end of each execution.

```
@EnableScheduling
public class DynamicSchedulingConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private TickService tickService;

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
          new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  tickService.tick();
              }
          },
          new Trigger() {
              @Override
              public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext context) {
                  Optional<Date> lastCompletionTime =
                    Optional.ofNullable(context.lastCompletionTime());
                  Instant nextExecutionTime =
                    lastCompletionTime.orElseGet(Date::new).toInstant()
                      .plusMillis(tickService.getDelay());
                  return Date.from(nextExecutionTime);
              }
          }
        )
    }

}
```